# How to arrange views on the screen?

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a button, a textView and a scrolView on my screen. I need the button and textView to be beside each other on top and the scrolView under them. How to professionally arrange views on the screen?!

this is what I have done:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:textDirection="inherit"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnScanAndDraw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="@string/btnShoePosition"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:onClick="ScanAndDraw"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewMap"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: First step: try something.

Comment: so I made a linear layout on top. but all of them are going beside each other. I tried the margin_top attribute for the views but just want to know is it the best way or there is any other way!

Comment: It's easier to post some code with a screenshot of what the layout looks like.

Comment: ok @mikeyaworski I did it :)

Comment: Now people can copy that code into their own xml and manipulate it themselves. A screenshot of the layout would be nice too, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I red a book for android app development. reading the book I realized that it is possible to have several LinearLayout s which will go inside of each other. Using this hierarchy of LinearLayout s I am able to arrange views in the .XML file. For instance I arranged a root LinearLayout which by itself contains 3 more LinearLayouts. For the buttons on top, I wrote:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

then the buttons went to right on top. For the ImageView - under the buttons - I implemented another LinearLayout that has this line of code inside to horizontally center the ImageView:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

In this form - as I said - using inner LinearLayouts and gravity it is possible to arrange views on the screen as intended.

may be useful for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want actually. If you are asking questions related to layout, please post a screenshot too. If I understood your question, solution is below.

You are using a `LinearLayout`, which has only two orientations (vertical and horizontal). [Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) to know about `LinearLayout`. If you want to arrange your UI in a relative manner use `RelativeLayout`. [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). I have changed your code with some new attributes. It's not tested, but it should give you desired output.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnScanAndDraw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="@string/btnShoePosition"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:onClick="ScanAndDraw"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txvMain/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/txvMain
        />

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewMap"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It makes changes, Thanks but it will cover my button and the text view. I just want to place the scrolView under the button and text view on the screen.

Comment: I changed the orientation of linear layout to vertical. Now all of them are vertically arranged under each other. Do you know how to put only the imageView under the two others?